# Eigenvalue-like problem with coupled ODEs

Tags: ode, eigensystem, matrix-equations

I am looking at the following system of ODEs:

\begin{array}{r}{\left[c_{2}(k)-\partial_{\tau}^{2}\right] \varphi_{2}\left(\tau \right)=f_{21}(\tau) \varphi_{1}\left(\tau \right)} \\ 
 {\left[c_{1}(k)-\partial_{\tau}^{2}\right] \varphi_{1}\left(\tau \right)=f_{11}(\tau) \varphi_{1}\left(\tau \right)+f_{12}(\tau) \varphi_{2}\left(\tau \right)} \end{array}

where $c_1(k)$ and $c_2(k)$ are known scalar functions of an unknown number $k$ and $f_{21}, f_{12}, f_{11}$ are known functions.
The unknowns are $k, \varphi_{1,2}$ and I'd like to find $k$ numerically.

When there's only one ODE, $c(k)$ can be obtained by discretising time and solving a matrix eigenvalue problem:

\begin{array}{r}{\left[c(k)-\partial_{\tau}^{2}\right] \varphi\left(\tau \right)=f(\tau) \varphi\left(\tau \right)}  \end{array}

I am curious if I can recast the coupled problem as a (generalized)eigenvalue problem as well?
Otherwise, another possibility is to try a bisection-like method to find the correct $k$ so that the matrix is singular, but this seems clunky.

Any comments/references appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: It comes up in the context of studying growth rate of perturbations in certain dynamical systems. But, I have a feeling it appears more generally!

Comment: I think that depending on the form of $c(k)$ it can be written as a polynomial or nonlinear eigenvalue problem.

Comment: @KartMan, I have a Mathematica package that can solve this kind of eigenvalue problem, if it is of interest to you

Answer (score 2):

Assume the equations are discretized on the $\tau$ grid, and introduce several column-vectors, using the notation where the superscript stands for the grid point index i $\in$ [1,...,n].

$\vec{\tau}=\left[ \tau^1,\tau^2,...,\tau^{n} \right] $

$\vec{\phi_1}=\left[ \phi_1^1,\phi_1^2,...,\phi_1^{n} \right] $

$\vec{\phi_2}=\left[ \phi_2^1,\phi_2^2,...,\phi_2^{n} \right] $

$\vec{f_{11}}=\left[ f_{11}^1,f_{11}^2,...,f_{11}^{n} \right] $

$\vec{f_{12}}=\left[ f_{12}^1,f_{12}^2,...,f_{12}^{n} \right] $

$\vec{f_{21}}=\left[ f_{21}^1,f_{21}^2,...,f_{21}^{n} \right] $

Next, the second derivative operator on the grid is a matrix 
$\hat{\Delta}$ of size $n \times n$.

Also, use $\alpha (k) = c_2(k) / c_1(k)$, and denote
$c_1(k) = \lambda$ and $c_2(k) = \alpha \lambda$

Now, let's write both equations as a single linear system of size 
$2n \times 2n$ for the compound state column-vector $\vec{\phi}$ which is

\begin{equation}
\vec{\phi} = [\phi_1^1,\phi_1^2,...,\phi_1^{n},\phi_2^1,\phi_2^2,...,\phi_2^{n}]
\end{equation}

We'll use here several matrices of size $2n \times 2n$:

The left hand side matrix $L$
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{I} & \hat{0}\\
\hat{0} & \alpha \hat{I}
\end{bmatrix}

the differential operator matrix $D$
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\Delta} & \hat{0}  \\
\hat{0} & \hat{\Delta}
\end{bmatrix}

the cross-coupling matrix $C$
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{0}             & \hat{I} \vec{f_{12}} \\
\hat{I} \vec{f_{21}} & \hat{0}
\end{bmatrix}

and the forcing term matrix $F$
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{I} \vec{f_{11}} & \hat{0}  \\
\hat{0}             & \hat{0}
\end{bmatrix}

Here $\hat{I}$ is the unit matrix of size $n \times n$,
$\hat{0}$ is the null matrix of size $n \times n$.

Now our problem can be written as

\begin{equation}
\lambda L \vec{\phi} =
\left(
D + C + F
\right) \vec{\phi}
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
\lambda \vec{\phi} =
L^{-1} \left(
D + C + F
\right) \vec{\phi}
\tag{*}\label{*}
\end{equation}

This a linear eigenvalue problem, where the right hand side matrix contains the parameter $\alpha$, so the eigenvalues are functions of $\alpha$, which in turn is a function of $k$.

For a given value of $k$ there is a spectrum of eigenvalues, $\lambda_0, \lambda_1$ etc. Let's say we are interested in the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ which we'd just call $\lambda$. Solution of the eigenvalue problem 
$\eqref{*}$ by standard methods of linear algebra defines a function $\lambda(k)$, on the other hand by construction $\lambda$ must be equal to $c_1(k)$. The root of the equation $\lambda(k) = c_1(k)$ (if it exists) defines the solution of the problem. Since $\lambda(k)$ and $c_1(k)$ are two nonlinear functions the root of the equation $\lambda(k) = c_1(k)$ has to be sought by some iterative numerical technique.

Comment: How is this a linear eigevalue problem when both $\lambda$ and $L$ are functions of the unknown $k$ which needs to be determined?

Comment: It is a linear eigenvalue problem for determining $\lambda$, as long as $\alpha$ is given. But if you need to find $k$ then you have to solve the nonlinear problem $c_1(k) = \lambda(k)$ using the above machinery.

Comment: well, as I had described in the orginal post, $k$ and thus $c(k)$ are unknown and need to be determined. I don't see how this formulation casts the problem of finding $k$ into an eigenvalue/generalised eigenvalue problem.

Comment: I added some explanations on how that could be done. To determine $k$ you have to solve a nonlinear equation; but for your example with a single ODE you'd have to do it as well, to solve $c(k)=\lambda$.

Comment: if you can find $\lambda$ getting $k$ is quite easy in my case. There's no numerics required. Also, I had indicated in my earlier post that you can do some iterative (e.g. bisection method) procedure to get $k$ but this is not the eigenvalue formulation. I don't think what you wrote describes this as any eigenvalue problem.

Comment: The structure of the solution for a single ODE: (1) solving the eigenvalue problem for $\lambda$, and (2) solving the nonlinear equation $c(k)=\lambda$. In the proposed solution for two equations it is similar, (1) solving a sequence of eigenvalue problems to determine $\lambda(k)$, and (2) solving the nonlinear equation $c_1(k) = \lambda(k)$. I would expect that the approach I propose will work way better than trying to solve this directly by brute force as a large nonlinear problem $det(M(k))=0$, just because a large part of the problem is handled by a eigenvalue solver.